# No FIN flags set in Wireshark trace

Tags: tcp, wireshark, handshake

I have a trace from http://example.com.  I can see the `SYN` and `ACK` and the other TCP goodies, however there's no `FIN`.

I've tries some other sites as well, still no `FIN`.

Are all the webservers/browsers misbehaving and not closing as they should, or is this correct behavior and to so with reusing connections (or something else)?

Comment: It is correct. HTTP/1.1 keeps the connection alive by default. Wait for the timeout, then you'll see the FIN.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the browser after visiting the page?  Try that, and see if now you see the FIN when the browser exits.